# Function wrapper statically checking parameters for HTTP response

Tags: typescript, response, wrapper, http-status-codes, payload

i am trying to implement a type assertion wrapper for function calling Express'es chain `res.status(..).json(..)`. I think i am "already there", but i stuck. The goal is to statically check whether:

- passed HTTP status code conforms certain response payload
- response payload has certain value

**TypeScript playground demo (full implementation attempt):** [click](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6&ts=4.1.5#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-e7PSHXf6YYTHXDEcjUeiiB7icgHfH0Ei2cmA2oKXH4VnE+yU57M9mkxi88whcHmayq2W006G0Qc9XfvKymBNBrkFw+xBhjAtc0dXqDUaTV8Zr2NZQYMgxx1un0BiNxu1VAx5yguO1WAgkKRSDBFGOJ-rDcayDxRnq4NNkHdfIfj6FzworwbkKBkPwmiLgOQ4jpeurXtOZC+F6Lq+m6Dr+P4wjNMACC8KY2IYDgeBIMQZBUDQEAig6GjaLoBAerIDohKe4QQA6ahuCUqh7gOgwKMAAhgPkhTgZON4zvej7Pq+HFceAvHGD+Xz-oBwGDhqYFNOOEFTrepAwRWJa5khKFoRh2G4Pg+EUNQtC2A68TGA6zGyqxQ4Du00AAG7QFJUD8ZBGnCbqolqG+rnuQU0lqbJIAARAQFLopw6jipMlQZprZECy7ZNohyHIKh6GmEZuGECQZlEZZ6SZNk1C2SxPaOVwXnqSavlPjMB5HieZ4XglYVJU1MhqFw4ncR59WCXelAPn50j9c5UBuVAw1dQJPXjY+O5sUV-nMKIAnCLsRgmsI8g4NAcrTB4RUwvMpC5MguwuXACisJELAgJop1TOdZCymU54gMsOQRRsxW0AA6ng6rQJhzATXAADSUVxGkkAgAQXzyUu+UmUVhG0Awbi7GoQMGGQMLbdewjo8ge7AaqEMECNUEwgQj7E0YJhQ-cMPw5otjYnVi3eY1K26r41NLmTBr+ExDCnXcGz6lAgNkCsEukLsqtyisV3ULszO6nKyjIAA9EbyDzAa1RPggHBwP+CAPQotjYOwTmfLQVRfGzGzLMgAAGetwL7VOOTAxg1NAur-r7qu+99DBKtUCTsNAwhGwAVMgBCsJgmCaMH5CSMgwHoGk5BA6QKxJ5AUDIGnpt3BEYC7RonBJJYNjIDAQjIOc9j-dQ70eC5lDAAQsqbcgjfN3qHBt5Ithd4PL6lKUDBV9AKyN7sDpGwGt0bAAjsIcCvbYRPIEVS93MAS67AAhIfKzYMamgrDoEigLL2LIPLrCKz-BFzIQDBmqDUUBdhA1sKSF8cQQpQEdCQA+T1lRkR0HoZAChEC8C+MBAARO-UAuC74enlLEVezBf7-yBjjYB4MwEQJJt8YUMDUEUVuCqUI9FHRXEoBICIBA-wgGIcgYopDZRyiAA)

**One of errors** from the list i receive in above linked TS demo code **[x]**:

> Property '200' does not exist on type 'THTTPStatusCodeToData'

**Wrapper implementation is:**

```
function responseWrapper<
  DataKey extends keyof IEmbracedResponse
>(
  res: Res,
  status: keyof typeof mappedHTTPStatusCode,
  data: Record<
    DataKey, 
    THTTPStatusCodeToData[typeof status] // <-- so far, problem is here [x]
  >
) {
  return res.status(status).json(data); // just a chain call, but TS asserts correct `data` type for certain `status`
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
router.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.body.login) {
     return responseWrapper(res, 400, { error: 'Request payload lacks of "login"!' });
  }

  return responseWrapper(res, 200, { payload: { isAdmin: true }});
})
```

**Example inputs and TS expected type checking results:**

```
responseWrapper(res, 200, { exception: Error('ups') }); // <-- fail, because 'exception' key cannot be associated with 200 status
responseWrapper(res, 500, { exception: 'something crashed'}); // <-- fail, because 'exception' cannot be a string, but Error object
responseWrapper(res, 200, { something: null}); // <-- fail, because status 200 cannot be associated with 'something' key
responseWrapper(res, 500, { error: 'ups' }); // <-- fail, because status 500 must be associated with 'exception' key, not the 'error' key

responseWrapper(res, 200, { payload: { isAdmin: true }}); // <-- ok, because status 200 can be associated with 'payload' key and the payload has object value
responseWrapper(res, 500, { exception: Error('ups') }); // <-- ok, because status 500 can be associated with 'exception' key and the value is Error object
responseWrapper(res, 400, { error: 'ups' }); // <-- ok, because status 400 can be associated with 'error' key and it's a string
```

---

So far i've used less advanced wrapper, just to check if passed object value is correctly associated with the key, but now i also want to have HTTP status regarding value association check:

```
const embraceResponse = <
  Key extends keyof IEmbracedResponse
>(response: Record<Key, IEmbracedResponse[Key]>) =>
  response;

// usage examples:
res.status(200).json(embraceResponse({ payload: { prop: true } }));
res.status(400).json(embraceResponse({ error: 'ups' }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for fully working playground :), I made some changes in your code, the key change is one solid type converting status to data. `responseWrapper` definition becomes simpler with it. And the checks, you provided, seem to be working now.

```
type StatusToData<status> = 
  status extends keyof TypeOfHTTPStatusCodes['SUCCESSFUL'] ? Pick<IEmbracedResponse,'payload'> | Pick<IEmbracedResponse,'message'>
  : status extends keyof TypeOfHTTPStatusCodes['CLIENT_ERROR'] ? Pick<IEmbracedResponse, 'error'> 
  : status extends keyof TypeOfHTTPStatusCodes['SERVER_ERROR'] ? Pick<IEmbracedResponse, 'exception'>
  : never;

function responseWrapper<
   Status extends keyof typeof mappedHTTPStatusCode
>(
  res: Res,
  status: Status ,
  data: StatusToData<Status>,
) {
  return res.status(status).json(data); 
}
```

[Full Code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6&ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEC2AjKiIAmAShAM4AOA9iKSgN4BQyycArmABYAqlA1hCABcyUmCigA5sgA+yEKwA2CgNxNk5OAE8FlOAWEkElKAQA8o8SAkAaZKxC8QlAO4gAfDLsOnrgNoBdVWZMMlI4CQhhC0kg5GgoYyixGLUIAA8kcjBgamF0KASoVQBfBgZ0qigwZCMaaoAJLi4ABQB9AGUuAEEuAFV21oBhAHkAEXR25ABeZGHsACsIBDAAOhgoCAgALwgACkZmdt7BwYn2gDFegBlhA+ZkACYABifhZ6eWUkeX6zVmZ4AjG8ngDPt8Ab9mMVIchBlcMAA5LitdBEIjDIi3P7IAAsL2EeI+cC+hJhzDxQNxILBFJh0LU7VRADVUSi0RisfdkABWfE8l5g3lPMk8gGU7liwViukMYoASjKtVEyEwcHI5EIjRa7TAcDArFIg0oBBQMzmi2Waw22z2d3ewgA5EcTmdLlcHWCncdTu0LtcHTDAY7nT6-e7PSHXf6YYTHXDEcjUeiiB7icgHfH0Ei2cmA2oKXH4VnE+yU57M9mkxi88whcHmayq2W006G0Qc9XfvKymBNBrkFw+xBhjAtc0dXqDUaTV8Zr2NZQYMgxx1un0BiNxu1VD2h8gJ-rSDxRnq4OZdYePDM1KJJ190pAQAQvvxNIuB0OR2OD1PjWRfF6Lq+m6Dr+MgAD8yDNMACC8KYGA4HgSDEGQVA0BA1gOho2i6AQDpuLI0GwfBWC4PgKEUNQtCYSEpBhBE+FqEkd5xGkj7Psgr7voOGpfk044Xr+M4ARWJa5mBkFEXBCFkchJCUehtgOvExj4cgTEiIJ95sQIHFcUuPHDqO-E-oaf6kABjJECy7ZNqBEFQTB0mkUhhDyWh1HpukmTZNQjHMMIIAQAAbtAO4MPOKBcO0rAIEgdEwIo35adOZDHqe0zIHcvgxXFoSJQopnIKAnEQG+BmfsZ2opeZlnelG7r+P4whSaY2Iya5FEeRh2JYVoOh6B6sgOrR9EQA6ahuCUqiRQOgwKMAAhgPkhTJXeqVHpQJ66pl2XzYt4ArcYRUlfpH68VVAnrbVGZFpWpagc1jnER15HuVRGFeQUqlTbKM17tF0ChVAR1QGth4belO0zNl7RA9AoMnSApXledRng0J-6ttZjYPU1LVOSRiFvahH1Kd5EBZDkID4dNu79lwGNmSaUNwJl0WxfFpAFUzkNbRl0hqFw+1LaDvPmazMhC3DUDA2LJk1TOrM7rN8m7TeWnCLsRgmoFrA4NAcrTB48kwvMpC5MguzBXACisJELAgJoRtTCbZCymUiUgMs1PIBsCm0AA6ng6rQG19xFQ+ukvmV76Re+qqhwQ4smgwbi7Go-sGGQMK3oewhFTCBCngXWms6YpluL8DBG3cGz6lAyP+ysecGrsrekHKKzm9QuzF7qcrKMgAD0w-IPMBrVGzCAcHAJUILbCi2Ng7ADpMxK0FUXxGAUSzVAABv3cD78gs0wMYNTQLqJX7x3+8ewwSrVAk7DQMIw8AFTIAQ+uYJop99kkMgd86A0jkH9qQFYL9IBQGQB-MedwIhgC1hoTgSRLA2GQDAIQyBzj2B9tQF2HhgqUGAAQWU6tmBIJQXqDg6DJC2GwUQrKpRSgRT3NtOA7xMqmXLu8X6s1OFCh4WXfmupTBCgERw08hIRF3nLoSX6DBoHQBWEg3YDph4BithsAAjsIOATtbBZ2QPJZhdxgBLl2AAQj0SsbAxpNArB0BIUAtdsR+wgA3JupN0LBzVBqKAux-a2FJFlOI30oCOhILo+2ypsIDQIMgBQiBeBfHfAAIhcaADJ1iPTyliGw5g-tur+NDkEkJ3xhThISbhW4KpQjhAdg6K4lAJARCSaAPJyBigFLUKPAAtEM4ZAzM6+KDiHQJwSc5VNsHQViPlqZ5EiRo1g5BSAOiNgUkeY9TBDKwXPJeyBsBLDYLQLyGRKa+RpijGohinDVBOZ8C2CBgB6kIMgZwwBOBVM0neMZAcIBlKmZUoUcyFlXKWemC2IROBAIQHgUgHBCAOm2aPZAeyBkHOAEck5C8DQoGUpcqmfk7kgAecclAbNohWGXqvUGwCFh7wBaUyZ0BpmkFsO8cFMKvEcEkHrJQaLdn7PgDi5epyCV-MPL8he5LKCPKpXRSgrz3lJK+T8h0vK4VWA9K+FlH1gXstBT8cJKkonpjWRsnpg8dkYtFYciV+Lzkd35B8TAk9KXPJVW8yA6rvkcAuYs0lr5bAUs4IS81eqyplGKeMoFbKKkzO5TU-qdTwnAFIF0AgmBQDCDEPbHpwr7VYr4E6s5KBXXcLlV6jePq1WfIDemWpg1bmGKSRG9Qaa9DIFnukplyxkA2zthAA1fjE0ctsGCs1xLrnLMKKs9ZmybVD3RZi4BvBy1StdcImtTy62qr9Y2zVFMSU3NfI7DtyKh220LZm5ADLKADrAGOiZATjUzLCfM81jorX5NtWu-ZZbKXOsrVpKkHw91Kpeb6j5GrA3KUidG-+7bipgC1SwTSGDZQKgYEAA)

Comment: I ended up with such an overkill, but it seems to work. https://github.com/ScriptyChris/Fake-PEV-Shopping/blob/b4321d940fea88ccc03d8dba74d17823c6cbfede/src/middleware/helpers/middleware-response-wrapper.ts